# Change the background color of a layout from the code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-drawable

I have a view that has a defined drawable background (that makes it a circle) and gives it a basic background color:
**circle_block.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#aaaaaa" />
</shape>
```

in the **activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/result_container"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_block"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
```

I tried changing only the background color from the code, but it didn't work.
**MainActivity.java:**

```
private LinearLayout container;
// on create
container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.result_container);
container.setBackgroundColor(0x4CAF50);
```

But it just turns white. It's important to retain to oval shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here

> container.setBackgroundColor(0x4CAF50);

This line will replace background which you are setting in xml using `circle_block.xml`

So if you want to change layout background drawable color then use `Drawable.setColorFilter` :

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_block);
drawable.setColorFilter(0x4CAF50, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
container.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

this will change color of shape which is currently in background of Layout

Comment: Hey, this doesn't change the background color. Thanks for the answer, anyway.

Comment: @Gofilord: you are using `0x4CAF50` which is not visible. check it with `Color.RED`

Comment: Well, that actually worked. But I don't see what's wrong with my color. How do I apply a hex color code?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I just had to use `Color.parseColor(mycolorstring)`

Answer (score 3):

Create colors.xml file in res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#ff64c2f4</color>
</resources>
```

And then:

```
container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It actually changes the background color, but it destroys the oval shape. The layout must remain a circle. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try following as you linearlayout consist of custom background

```
GradientDrawable drawable = container.getBackground();
drawable.setColor(yourcolorvalue);
```